# Element doesn't get destroyed on router navigation after manipulating DOM

Tags: angular

I have a directive that needs to move the element on which it is applied to the body of the document:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class MyDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private elem: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Move element to body
    this.renderer.appendChild(document.body, this.elem.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

Now I use this directive in an element with an `ngIf` that I toggle based on some condition:

```
<div myDirective *ngIf="visible">Test</div>
<button (click)="visible = !visible">Toggle</button>
```

When it runs, the div will show *after* the button as expected, because it was appended to the body. The toggle button still works at this point, and I can show/hide the div.

The problem comes when I introduce routes:

```
<a routerLink="/route/1">Link</a>
<div myDirective *ngIf="visible">Test</div>
<button (click)="visible = !visible">Toggle</button>
```

Now, if I show the div, and navigate to another route, the div should get destroyed, but it's still visible! If I don't move the div to the body then it behaves as expected.

First, I tried removing the element in `ngOnDestroy` but this doesn't work with animations, because it deletes the element *without* playing its :leave animation.

My current workaround is to inject the router into the directive and subscribe to the first event that comes through to restore the div to its original container:

```
this.routerSubscription = router.events.first().subscribe(() => {
  this.renderer.appendChild(this.parentNode, this.elem.nativeElement);
});
```

While this works, it is not great, as now the directive has a dependency in the router when it should really know nothing about it.

How can improve on this hack to make sure the element gets destroyed properly?

**DEMO:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qximjw?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

To reproduce the issue:

1. Make sure the URL it's at the root and not within a route
2. Click the toggle button
3. Click the link to navigate to the route
4. Watch the div NOT disappear

Answer (score 3):

You can add code to remove the element at `ngOnDestroy`:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  if (this.routerSubscription) {
    this.routerSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
  document.body.removeChild(this.elem.nativeElement);
}
```

But be aware that when you navigate to the **same** route, angular won't destroy it (this means ngOnDestroy won't trigger). You can try by add another route and navigate to it to confirm.

See [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-knfeze?file=app/app.component.ts).

Comment: The problem with this is that it won't work with animations, because the element will destroy when it toggles off and it will disappear immediately, without playing its animation. See here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cxwxsg?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @elclanrs sorry for late response. I don't think the animation here will work, for the browser is navigating to another page totally. What you can do is add some animations for leaving component.

Comment: I already did, that's the issue. If you see the demo above, the animation won't even work when you toggle it _without_ navigating away. The :leave animation will never play because ngOnDestroy removes the element before it gets a chance.

Comment: @elclanrs Agreed. Sorry, I didn't play with animation too much. :( Will do some research from now.

Comment: @elclanrs Have you tried to add the element to `AppComponent` not `document.body`? see [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-knfeze?file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 3):

Well i think it works as intended. If you use your browser inspect mode and click on the RouterLink button you will notice that the HomeComponent is getting re-rendered because you are serving the same Component on both of your Router Options.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'route/:id',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];
```

Therefore, if your Directive is appended and not removed from the DOM, when the HomeComponent gets rendered again, a new instance of that component and also your Directive will be created thus, the application will append an new `<div>` on your body while clicking the (new) Button. To make it more clear i suggest you to replace the HomeComponent code with the one below and check out your JavaScript Console.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'home-component',
  template: `
  <a routerLink="/route/1">Link</a>
  <div myDirective *ngIf="visible" @transition>Test</div>
  <button (click)="visible = !visible">Toggle</button>
  `,
  animations: [
    trigger('transition', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate('.35s ease', style({ opacity: '*' }))
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        style({ opacity: '*' }),
        animate('.35s ease', style({ opacity: 0 }))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class HomeComponent {
  visible = false;
  constructor() {
    console.log('New instance')
  }
}
```

A workaround that i can think of is putting the Toggle button outside the **router-outlet** boundaries inside a Component.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-toggle-button',
    template: `
    <div myDirective *ngIf="visible" @transition>Test</div>
    <button (click)="visible = !visible">Toggle</button>
    `,
    animations: [
      trigger('transition', [
        transition(':enter', [
          style({ opacity: 0 }),
          animate('.35s ease', style({ opacity: '*' }))
        ]),
        transition(':leave', [
          style({ opacity: '*' }),
          animate('.35s ease', style({ opacity: 0 }))
        ])
      ])
    ]
  })
  export class ToggleComponent {
    visible = false;
  }
```

And after that you can add it on your app.component.html file:

```
<app-toggle-button></app-toggle-button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In that case you will always have **A SINGLE** instance of the ToggleComponent even if you navigate through multiple Routes.

Let me know if that helped you, cheers.

Comment: I reused the same component for the purpose of the demo. In my actual code, they are two different components. You can see I added another compoennt, and the same behavior happens: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qximjw?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Then i think your problem will be solved if you follow the workaround i mentioned before. Create a component that is outside the router-outlet and never re-render it (never serve it with the router options). That way you will always have a single Component instance.

Comment: I cannot create the component outside. This is the use case of this directive, I cannot change how the template is setup.

Answer (score 0):

Use `routerLink` and `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` instead of going with below technique (I think it is older technique)

```js
gotoSignup() {
    this.router.navigate(['/signup']);  // define your component where you want to go
}
```

You can do something like this.

```html
<button mat-flat-button color="primary" routerLink="/login">Login</button>
<button mat-flat-button color="primary" routerLink="/signup">Signup</button>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Your Components will show in place of `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and they will destroy previous component. [[Source](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial)]

Thoughts:
I believe this way of routing is done because of the 'nature' of the Single Page Applications.